# Saving Video Files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, video, attachment

Okay, so i've used paperclip in the past to upload images and videos.  I was wondering.  Is there a simple way to save a video in rails?  I've got the form worked out to upload files, and i'm wondering if there is a certain type I should save it as. (Obviously not string, but along those lines.)  I simply want to have a video player with all three file types. (ogg, mp4, wav).  Just each one saved in their own row in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably going to want to take a look at [paperclip-ffmpeg](http://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg). I would save the different formats as **paperclip styles**. This should look very similar to your typical paperclip image upload where you process the image to generate different sizes, like *thumbnail* for example.

**Disclaimer:** With this way, you will need to install ffmpeg on your server. If you are on an Mac and use homebrew, this link is helpful. http://www.renevolution.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/

In the example below, let's say your file attachment in your database is set to `data`.

Run the migration to add the appropriate columns to your table.

```
> rails g migration add_data_to_videos data:attachment
```

Then in your model.

```
# Validations
validates_attachment_presence :data
validates_attachment_size :data, less_than: 100.megabytes # if you want a max file size
validates_attachment_content_type :data, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/ # or you can specify individual content types you want to allow

has_attached_file :data,
  url: '/videos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension', # whatever you want
  styles: {
    poster: { size: '640x480', format: 'jpg' }, # this takes a snapshot of the video to have as your poster
    v_large_webm: { geometry: '640x480', format: 'webm' }, # your webm format
    v_large_mp4: { geometry: '640x480', format: 'mp4' } # your mp4 format
  },
  processors: [:ffmpeg],
  auto_rotate: true
```

With this setup, your views will be very similar to using paperclip with images.

```
# To display the video (HTML5 way using HAML)
%video{controls: '', height: 'auto', width: '100%', poster: @video.data.url(:poster)}
  %source{src: @video.data.url(:v_large_mp4), type: 'video/mp4'}
  %source{src: @video.data.url(:v_large_webm), type: 'video/webm'}
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
```

I would also recommend looking into using background jobs to do the processing. Perhaps DelayedJob.